# Randomly placed divs not breaking the container

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm after is to improve my code. What I'm currently doing is I have a bunch of divs that have images, all positioned absolutely within a relative container. The top and left positions of the divs are calculated using some JS.

```
$('.each-artist-landing-image-container').each(function() {
    $(this).css({ 
        'top':  Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1) + 'px', 
        'left': Math.floor(Math.random() * 400 + 1) + 'px' 
    });
});
```

What is happening, which I don't want, however is that due to the positions... they are sometimes breaking out of the relative container due to the fact that the positions are random.

Is there any way to calculate the top and left positions but not breaking out of the relative container? I'm guessing it would need to get the image width and then make sure that width isn't sitting outside the container?

Thanks in advance,
R

Comment: Can you please post it on JsFiddle (with HTML and CSS), so we can see what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct, the code would be slightly modified to be as follows:

```
$('.each-artist-landing-image-container').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css({ 
        'top':  Math.floor((Math.random() * (300 - $this.height())) + 1) + 'px', 
        'left': Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - $this.width()) + 1) + 'px' 
    });
});
```